# Getting multiple check box values and put them into ICollection MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, web-applications, checkbox

I want to know how I can retrieve the values of multiple checkboxes. I have a diagram and some code, please take a look at it. There's a few steps that I need to do:

1. Put all categories from the Category table in the Product/Create file as Checkboxes (which will put the input in the Product table)
2. Retrieve the chosen Checkboxes
3. for each chosen checkbox, add the product to it's own list in the category table

Later on I have to display every category with their corresponding products.

I hope that makes sense. Here's my code. I do not want to create another file/model/view/controller, if possible. I translated everything to English so it's easier to read.

Category Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebshopMVC.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description{ get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Producten { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Product Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebshopMVC.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Description{ get; set; }
        public decimal Price{ get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories{ get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Offer> Offers{ get; set; }

    }
}
```

Product/Create View:

```
@model WebshopMVC.Models.Categorie

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    }

    <h2>Create</h2>


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Categorie</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Image)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
```

Product Controller(Create)

```
    public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: /Product/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific     properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include =          "ID,Image,Name,Description,Price,Categories")] Product product)
            {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Producten.Add(product);

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(product);
        }
```

And here's a Diagram of how it should be:

[image: Diagram]

It's just an Image and it's in Dutch, so I will give you the English translation:

```
Categorie => Category  
plaatje => Image
naam => Name
omschrijving => Description

Product => Product
plaatje => Image
naam => Name
omschrijving => Description
Prijs => Price
```

---

So, again:

1. Let user create a product and assign 1 or more categories, which will come out of the Categories Table
2. Get the selected categories, add them to the Categories list in the Product Model
3. Add the product to the Products list in the Categories model
4. Later on I have to be able to loop through the categories and get their products, so I can link to them 
   strong text

Steps 2 and 3 may seem a bit weird, but according to the model, a category has * products and a product has 1 or more categories, so I also coded it that way

I have been struggling with this for many hours now. If anyone could help me out I would be so thankful!

If you need any other information, I will gladly give it to you!

Edit:
I have added a viewmodel to my project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebshopMVC.Models
{

    public class ProductCategoryViewModel
    {
        public string Image{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description{ get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Categorie> Categories { get; set; }

        public ProductCategoryViewModel()
        {
            Categories = Categories.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

I've also altered the Product/Create.cshtml file:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Categories)
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
                {
                    <input type="checked" name="Categories" value="@(item.Name)">@(item.Name)
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

I now get an error when I try to go to the Product/Create page:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Line 54)

```
Line 52:             @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.categories)  
Line 53:             <div class="col-md-10">  
Line 54:                 @foreach (var item in Model.categories)  
Line 55:                 {  
Line 56:                     <input type="checked" name="Categories" value="@(item.Name)">@(item.Name)
```

I don't know how to fix this error and I also don't understand how this works.
How does this ProductCategoryViewModel retrieve the information from the database/Category table. I don't see a link anywhere.

I'll add my Class Diagram, maybe that helps:

[image: Database Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ViewModel` and put `IEnumerable<Categories>` in it. Then you can use a for loop to bind checkboxes with individual items.

```
public class ProductCategoryViewModel
{
    public string Image{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Description{get;set;}
    public double Price{get;set;}

    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories{get;set;}

    public ()
    {
        Categories = Categories.GetAll().ToList();
    }
}

@foreach (var item in Model.Categories) {
    <input type="checked" name="Categories" value="@(item.Name)">@(item.Name)
    //or use html helper which will add hidden input as well
    // @Html.CheckboxFor(x=> x.Name);
}
```

**EDIT:-** You need to declare model to be used in view at top of your `cshtml` file:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProductCategoryViewModel>
```

Then you need to set this from controller action:

```
var vm = new ProductCategoryViewModel();
return new View("Create", vm);
```

Also this will not work:

```
public ProductCategoryViewModel()
{
    Categories = Categories.ToList();
}
```

`Categories` is not populated yet so this statement is useless. You need to get categories from somewhere (like Database) and set this property. Like,

```
public ProductCategoryViewModel()
{
    Categories = <GET FROM DATABASE>;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Do I need to create another class? Do I have to put this in my Models folder? The @foreach is in my Product/Create view, right? Then how do I access the ProductCategoryViewModel when I am already using the Product model? I also don't know how to retrieve the values of those checkboxes. Could you help me out?

Comment: I've added extra information to my post @TheVillageIdiot . Could you take a look at it ?